# String copy in Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, intel-syntax

I've got a problems with copying string to empty array in Assembly.

Firstly, I get some junks instead string which i would like to copy.

Secondly, the program should work with string up to 100 chars but when I declare an array with 100 chars, I got "****** stack smashing detected ******" after compile using gcc.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    char *s="aac";
    char t[4];
    asm volatile ( 
        ".intel_syntax noprefix;" 
        "mov eax, %0;"
        "push eax;" 
        "mov eax, %1;"
        "push eax;" 
        "call printing;"
        "jmp end;"
        "printing:"
        "push ebp;" 
        "mov ebp,esp;" 
        "push eax;"
        "push ebx;" 
        "push ecx;"
        "push edx;" 

        "mov ebx,[ebp+12];"
        "mov eax,[ebp+8];"

        "mov ecx,eax;"

        "copying:"
        "mov dl,[ebx];"
        "mov [eax],dl;"
        "inc ebx;"
        "inc eax;"
        "cmp dl,0;"
        "jnz copying;"

        "xor edx,edx;"

        "mov eax,4;"
        "mov ebx,1;"

        "mov edx,3;"
        "int 0x80;"
        "pop edx;"
        "pop ecx;"
        "pop ebx;"
        "pop eax;"
        "pop ebp;"
        "ret 4;"

        "end:"

        ".att_syntax prefix;"
    :
    :"r" (s), "r" (t)
    :"eax"
    );

printf("\n");

}
```

I'm newbie in Assembly so please help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see four problems with your code:

- You are using the register `al` as buffer for transferring characters, while at the same time, you are using `eax` as source pointer. `al` is just a name for the lowest eight bits of `eax` so you are clobbering your source pointer. You might want to use `edx` instead. Clobbering the source pointer results in indeterminate copying lengths and can likely overflow your destination buffer on the stack, which will cause the stack smashing error.
- The destination buffer on the stack is too small. You are trying to copy 3 characters and the NUL byte, which needs four bytes in the destination buffer.
- You are passing the value of `eax` *after* the loop to the `write` syscall. This points past the copy destination, as you increased `eax` during the loop. If you copy `eax` to `ecx` before the copy loop, that problem is fixed.
- finally, you copy three non-NUL characters, but print only two.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand it at all. Could you show pieces of my code which I should change?

Comment: The other answer already addressed the first point, so you don't have to do anything about that one at all. The second point is targeting the declaration of t in your example. The third point is talking about the position of the "mov ecx, eax" instruction and the last bullet point is about the count argument passed to the write linux system call (as its the third parameter, it's passed in edx)

Comment: Ok. I think that I correct it with your suggestions and it works. Thank you so much. But I've got still statement: "*** stack smashing detected ***". Why?

Comment: Oops, it seems I missed another mistake in your code. The number after the return instruction contains the number of bytes of parameters to remove from the stack. You are pushing 2 values of 32 bits (the source and the destination pointer), so this makes 8 bytes total. Thus you need to change ret 4 to ret 8.

Comment: Ok, It works. :) Is it depend on how many variables I used and pushed on the stack?

Comment: The assembler code you quote contains a structure that is typically identified as subfunction. This is the part from the "printing:" label to before the "end:" label. The subfunction in that code is accepting parameters on the stack (a typical, but not very fast calling convention). The calling code pushes these parameters to the stack, and someone has to remove them again, to clean up the stack. The cited code decided to let the subfunction clean the stack (using ret with number), so that number has to match the bytes pushed. This is called "stdcall" convention by windows people.

Comment: One other point: Since you are modifying memory and flags, you should add "memory" and "cc" to the clobber list.